# How to deal with strings containing character codes?

Tags: python, string, character-encoding

`\201` is a character code recognised in Python. What is the best way to ignore this in strings?

```
s = '\2016' 
s = s.replace('\\', '/')
print s #6
```

Comment: s = r'\2016' for example ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "ignore"? It looks like you already know how to escape a backslash, so I'm guessing you aren't trying to do that.

Comment: Are you asking how to _create_ a string that consists of the five characters `\2016`, or how to turn a string that is _already_ `'\2016'` into `'2016'`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have a string literal with a backslash in it, you can escape the backslash:

```
s = '\\2016'
```

or you can use a "raw" string:

```
s = r'\2016'
```